# The image size of action bar in android app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

In android app, I would like to fix an action bar to the bottom of the screen.

The action bar has 6 icons.

I wrote down the following code.

In Galaxy Note3(Andoid4.4.2) it goes well. However, in Experia SOL21(Android4.1.2), the icon size is not adjusted to the appropriate size like below image.

Could you tell me how to fix this problem?

[Image in Experia SOL21(Android4.1.2)]
[[image: Image in Experia SOL21(Android4.1.2)]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1hqN.png)
<sub>(source: [it-techintern.com](http://it-techintern.com/image1.png))</sub>

[My code]

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.DetailActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
```

in Activity.java

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem actionItemBack = menu.add("Back");
    MenuItem actionItemForward = menu.add("Forward");
    MenuItem actionItemLine = menu.add("Twitter");
    MenuItem actionItemTw = menu.add("icon4");
    MenuItem actionItemFb = menu.add("icon5");
    MenuItem actionItemFav = menu.add("icon6");

    actionItemBack.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    actionItemForward.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    actionItemLine.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    actionItemTw.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    actionItemFb.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    actionItemFav.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    actionItemBack.setIcon(R.drawable.back);
    actionItemForward.setIcon(R.drawable.next);
    actionItemLine.setIcon(R.drawable.twitter);
    actionItemTw.setIcon(R.drawable.icon4);
    actionItemFb.setIcon(R.drawable.icon5);
    actionItemFav.setIcon(R.drawable.icon6);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: As usual, provide **different graphics** for **different screen densities**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to get different size of images like

48*48 size image put in drawable-hdpi folder.

32*32 size image put in drawable-mdpi folder.

64*64 size image put in drawable-xhdpi folder.

96*96 size image put in drawable-xxhdpi folder.

Answer (score 2):

They have to be 32x32dp, but the actual image itself should be 24dpx24dp centred. The Android design website has the [correct guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar).

see [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) also

Comment: So should I make the image size 24dp x 24dp regardless of screen density such as xdpi, xxdpi?